# Air conditioning hisses, but gauges show pressure, no cold air

Tags: ac, diagnostics

So my 2010 VW Routan's (basically a Dodge Caravan) AC has gradually stopped working.  I figured I had a small leak and it finally just didn't have enough juice to cool.

I have a set of gauges that I'm not an expert with, but I know the basics.  The temperature outside was around 70, and the AC had been running for a few minutes.

[image]

The low side was 25psi, and the high side is 225psi.  Based on a few generic charts I found, it looks like, if anything, the low side is low and the high side is high for my ambient temp.

What could the issue be?  Can I do any other test or take a better measurement to narrow the possibilities?